# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker even though I detached it

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, caching

I'm using EF. I save entities into cache.

I detach each entity before putting into cache,

and attaching it to a new objectContext after getting from cache.

I'm using `using` statement at a high point (in my BL class, upon every request)

Yet I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.VerifyContextForAddOrAttach(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachSingleObject(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, EntitySet entitySet, String argumentName)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachTo(String entitySetName, Object entity)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Attach(Object entity)
at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Attach(TEntity entity)
at Conduit.Mam.ClientService.DAL.MamData.MamDataRepository.GetMamData(String stamp, MaMDBEntities maMDBEntities) in d:\Builds\TFS\9\221\Sources\Server\ClientServices\Dev\ClientService 1.3\ServiceDAL\MamData\MamDataRepository.cs:line 56
at Conduit.Mam.ClientService.BLL.MamDataManager.GetMamData() in d:\Builds\TFS\9\221\Sources\Server\ClientServices\Dev\ClientService 1.3\Conduit.Mam.ClientService.BLL\MamDataManager.cs:line 57
at Conduit.Mam.ClientService.BLL.AppsDataManager.GetClientRelevantsApps(List`1 appsData) in d:\Builds\TFS\9\221\Sources\Server\ClientServices\Dev\ClientService 1.3\Conduit.Mam.ClientService.BLL\AppsDataManager.cs:line 107
at Conduit.Mam.ClientService.Service.Controllers.ClientDataController.GetAppsData() in d:\Builds\TFS\9\221\Sources\Server\ClientServices\Dev\ClientService 1.3\Conduit.Mam.ClientService.Service\Controllers\ClientDataController.cs:line 58
```

Here is my detach + attach code:
The `using` inject the objectContext to here:

```
public static Group GetMamData(string stamp, MaMDBEntities maMDBEntities)
    {
        Group group = MamDataCacheManager.GetMamData(stamp);

        if (group == null)
        {
            //was not found in the cache
            //check for aveilable test with status 'start' - 1
            group = GetGroupsFromDb(stamp, maMDBEntities);

            if (group != null)
            {
                maMDBEntities.Entry(group).State = EntityState.Detached;

                MamDataCacheManager.InsertMamData(stamp, group);

            }
        }

        //option B: attache a new context
        if (maMDBEntities.Entry(group).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            maMDBEntities.Groups.Attach(group);
        }

        return group;
    }
```

The first time (getting fresh entity from DB into cache):

the entity is detached and attached to the same contextObjec.

The second time (getting the entity from the cache),

it's only attached to a new contextObject.

Do I have to do any additional step? Is my detach missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detach only affects the specific object passed to the method. If the object being detached has related objects in the object context, those objects are not detached.